# PHP SOAP - could not connect to host

Tags: php, soap, cron, wsdl

We are integrating our products our store in n11 with XML. We do them with php SOAP.

We did product update operations either locally or via the server in two ways. We did not encounter a problem when we performed these operations locally. But, when we try to implement it through the server, we encounter a "could not connect to host" error. When we try as a single cron with a single API key, we get this error after updating about 100 products. When we try 5 different api keys and 5 different cron, about 10-20 items are updated for all and then we get the same error again.

We have not been able to resolve this error for 2 weeks.

We have implemented most of the solutions mentioned in this website or other websites. We have tried methods such as cache change and domain name resolution which are mentioned in these pages. And a few other things.

And then...
We compared the local and server phpinfo values. The differences have been changed by experts we receive server service. But again we got the same error.

Because of these interruptions, 50 thousand products updates can take hours.
Do we have software shortcomings or ask you to tell us which setting to change on the server side.We ask you to help.

SOAP Connections

```
<?php

/**
* 
*/

class n11 {

    protected static $_appKey, $_appSecret, $_parameters, $_sclient;
    public $_debug = false;

    public function __construct(array $attributes = array()) {
        self::$_appKey = $attributes['appKey'];
        self::$_appSecret = $attributes['appSecret'];
        self::$_parameters = ['auth' => ['appKey' => self::$_appKey, 'appSecret' => self::$_appSecret]];
    }

    public function setUrl($url) {
        self::$_sclient = new \SoapClient($url);
    }

    public function GetTopLevelCategories() {
        $this->setUrl('https://api.n11.com/ws/CategoryService.wsdl');
        return self::$_sclient->GetTopLevelCategories(self::$_parameters);
    }

    public function GetSubCategories($categoryId) {
        $this->setUrl('https://api.n11.com/ws/CategoryService.wsdl');
        self::$_parameters['categoryId'] = $categoryId;
        return self::$_sclient->GetSubCategories(self::$_parameters);
    }

    public function GetCities() {
        $this->setUrl('https://api.n11.com/ws/CityService.wsdl');
        return self::$_sclient->GetCities(self::$_parameters);
    }

    public function GetProductList($itemsPerPage, $currentPage) {
        $this->setUrl('https://api.n11.com/ws/ProductService.wsdl');
        self::$_parameters['pagingData'] = ['pageSize' => $itemsPerPage, 'currentPage' => $currentPage];
        return self::$_sclient->GetProductList(self::$_parameters);
    }

    public function GetCategoryAttributes($categoryId) {
        $this->setUrl('https://api.n11.com/ws/CategoryService.wsdl');
        self::$_parameters['categoryId'] = $categoryId;
        return self::$_sclient->GetCategoryAttributes(self::$_parameters);
    }

    public function GetProductByProductId($productId) {
        $this->setUrl('https://api.n11.com/ws/ProductService.wsdl');
        self::$_parameters['productId'] = $productId;
        return self::$_sclient->GetProductByProductId(self::$_parameters);
    }

    public function GetProductBySellerCode($sellerCode) {
        $this->setUrl('https://api.n11.com/ws/ProductService.wsdl');
        self::$_parameters['sellerCode'] = $sellerCode;
        return self::$_sclient->GetProductBySellerCode(self::$_parameters);
    }

    public function StopSellingProductByProductId($productId) {
        $this->setUrl('https://api.n11.com/ws/ProductSellingService.wsdl');
        self::$_parameters['productId'] = $productId;
        return self::$_sclient->StopSellingProductByProductId(self::$_parameters);
    }

    public function SaveProduct(array $product = Array()) {
        $this->setUrl('https://api.n11.com/ws/ProductService.wsdl');
        self::$_parameters['product'] = $product;
        return self::$_sclient->SaveProduct(self::$_parameters);
    }

    public function UpdateProductPriceBySellerCode($productSellerCode, $price) {
        $this->setUrl('https://api.n11.com/ws/ProductService.wsdl');
        self::$_parameters['productSellerCode'] = $productSellerCode;
        self::$_parameters['price'] = $price;
        self::$_parameters['currencyType'] = 1;
        self::$_parameters['stockItems'] = [
            'stockItem' => [
                'sellerStockCode' => '',
                'optionPrice' => $price
            ]
        ];
        return self::$_sclient->UpdateProductPriceBySellerCode(self::$_parameters);
    }

    public function UpdateProductPriceById($productId, $price) {
        $this->setUrl('https://api.n11.com/ws/ProductService.wsdl');
        self::$_parameters['productId'] = $productId;
        self::$_parameters['price'] = $price;
        self::$_parameters['currencyType'] = 1;
        self::$_parameters['stockItems'] = [
            'stockItem' => [
                'sellerStockCode' => '',
                'optionPrice' => $price
            ]
        ];
        return self::$_sclient->UpdateProductPriceById(self::$_parameters);
    }

    public function UpdateStockByStockId($stockItem) {
        $this->setUrl('https://api.n11.com/ws/ProductStockService.wsdl');
        self::$_parameters['stockItems'] = [
            'stockItem' => $stockItem
        ];
        return self::$_sclient->UpdateStockByStockId(self::$_parameters);
    }

    public function UpdateProductBasic(array $product = Array()) {
        $this->setUrl('https://api.n11.com/ws/ProductService.wsdl');
        foreach ($product as $key => $value) {
            self::$_parameters[$key] = $value;
        }
        return self::$_sclient->UpdateProductBasic(self::$_parameters);
    }

    public function GetProductStockByProductId($productId) {
        $this->setUrl('https://api.n11.com/ws/ProductStockService.wsdl');
        self::$_parameters['productId'] = $productId;
        return self::$_sclient->GetProductStockByProductId(self::$_parameters);
    }

    public function DeleteProductBySellerCode($sellerCode) {
        $this->setUrl('https://api.n11.com/ws/ProductService.wsdl');
        self::$_parameters['productSellerCode'] = $sellerCode;
        return self::$_sclient->DeleteProductBySellerCode(self::$_parameters);
    }

    public function UpdateDiscountValueByProductId($productId, $productDiscount) {
        $this->setUrl('https://api.n11.com/ws/ProductService.wsdl');
        self::$_parameters['productId'] = $productId;
        self::$_parameters['productDiscount'] = $productDiscount;
        return self::$_sclient->UpdateDiscountValueByProductId(self::$_parameters);
    }

    public function OrderList(array $searchData = Array()) {
        $this->setUrl('https://api.n11.com/ws/OrderService.wsdl');
        self::$_parameters['searchData'] = $searchData;
        return self::$_sclient->OrderList(self::$_parameters);
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        if ($this->_debug) {
            print_r(self::$_parameters);
        }
    }

}
```

?>

Local phpinfo;
http://213.159.7.86/~kongoru/local.html

Server phpinfo
http://213.159.7.86/~kongoru/deneme.php

Comment: SOAP Code file : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_wf0ec6gICCenU1bTVwcWN5bjA

Comment: Are you sending 50,000 product updates using 50,000 SOAP calls?  For bulk data SOAP works better if you upload a package of N updates at once so there would be (50,000 / N) calls.  Best is if you upload say a zip archive then have an import job.

Comment: We do not know how to do this. We do product updates to the servers of other e-commerce pages.  Do we have to have specific authorities to do this on the other side? Or can we do it with a few software changes?  Are we able to do this with the SOAP structure on the other side's servers?
Best Ragards.

Comment: For this to work the server side needs SOAP functions that accept bulk lists of changes either as XML in the SOAP message or (better) as a compressed file.  If you only control the code on the client side and there is no bulk API on the server then you can't do this.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue ? I am facing it as well...